# TreeView with checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I need to build a javascript function that select the parent automatically when I select one child. For example I have a parent with 3 child, As soon as I click one child, the parent should be selected as well, and bubble up until the root. the same logic when I unclick the child I should uncheck all the parent.
Where can I find this logic?

Comment: use jQuery, and .parent() to move up the tree until .parent() returns the body

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
<ul>
  <li>Parent
    <ul>
      <li>Child 1</li>
      <li>Child 2</li>
      <li>Child 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You may do:

```
$('li li').click(function () {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#eee');
  $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#eee');
});
```

To do click and unclick you may use `.data()` to tag the child element in order to keep track of click / unclick. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have working example. Also add jQuery to this example and tree structure you can define with [] arrays. The checkboxes will change as you described. You can also generate tree in server side or enhance structure for your needs to put in data to display at time of parsing array tree. I didnt check for cross browser compatibility.

To get jQuery, go here http://jquery.com/download/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var tree = 
[
    [
        [
            [],
            []
        ],
        []
    ],
    [],
    [
        [],
        [
            [],
            []
        ]
    ]
]

document.ready = function()
{
    window.Cont = $("#container");
    treeGen(tree, Cont);
    Cont.find("input[type='checkbox']").click(checkboxClick)
}

var treeGen = function(arr, elem)
{
    if (arr !== true)
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
        {
            var newElem = $("<div></div>");
            $("<input type='checkbox'/>").appendTo(newElem);
            newElem.appendTo(elem);
            treeGen(arr[i], newElem);
        }
}

var checkboxClick = function()
{
    walkToRoot($(this).parent().parent(), $(this).is(":checked"))
}

var walkToRoot = function(elem, state)
{
    if (elem.attr("id") != "container")
    {
        var cBox = elem.find("input[type='checkbox']").first();
        cBox.get(0).checked = state;
        walkToRoot(elem.parent(), state);
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    #container div
    {
        margin-left:50px;
        margin-bottom:4px;
    }
</style>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on how you build the tree view.
Assuming the following HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox">A</input>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" />Once</input>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox">One</input></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Two</input></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Three</input></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Two</input></li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox">Three</input>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox">One</input></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Two</input></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox">Three</input></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="checkbox">B</input>
  <ul>
    <li><input type="checkbox">One</input></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Two</input></li>
    <li><input type="checkbox">Three</input></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

You can implement it using JQuery selectors:

```
$('li :checkbox').change(function() {
var $parent = $(this).parents().eq(2);
$parent.children('li :checkbox')
    .prop('checked', $parent.find('li :checkbox:checked').size() > 0)
    .change();
});
```

Here is a link to the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xEbPn/1/